# Using Regexp to catch substring python

Tags: python, regex

Let's assume I have some string like that:

```
x = 'Wish she could have told me herself. @NicoleScherzy #nicolescherzinger #OneLove #myfav #MyQueen :heavy_black_heart::heavy_black_heart: some string too :smiling_face:'
```

So, I want to get from that :

```
:heavy_black_heart:
:smiling_face:
```

To do that I did the following :

```
import re
result = re.search(':(.*?):', x)
result.group()
```

It only gives me the `':heavy_black_heart:'` . How could I make it work ? If possible I want to store them in dictonary after I found all of them.

Comment: Maybe `set(re.findall(r':[^:]+:', x))` will do? Not sure what there might be between `:`, maybe `r':\w+:'` will work better.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for the example, it works, but I couldn't understand why you're not sure

Comment: See my answer with some explanations. Actually, you have not provided all the requirements, just two examples, that is why I said I was not sure.

Comment: Do you really want to match `::`? As I said, you did not post exact specs. If you need to match any chars inside `:...:` that are not whitespaces, use `:[^\s:]+:` - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to match smilies that are some symbols in-between 2  `:`s. The `.*?` can match 0 symbols, and your regex can match `::`, which I think is not what you would want to get. Besdies, `re.search` only returns one - the first - match, and to get multiple matches, you usually use `re.findall` or `re.finditer`.

I think you need

```
set(re.findall(r':[^:]+:', x))
```

or if you only need to match word chars inside `:...:`:

```
set(re.findall(r':\w+:', x))
```

or - if you want to match any non-whitespace chars in between two `:`:

```
set(re.findall(r':[^\s:]+:', x))
```

The `re.findall` will find all non-overlapping occurrences and `set` will remove dupes.

The patterns will match `:`, then 1+ chars other than `:` (`[^:]+`) (or 1 or more letters, digits and `_`) and again `:`.

```
>>> import re
>>> x = 'Wish she could have told me herself. @NicoleScherzy #nicolescherzinger #OneLove #myfav #MyQueen :heavy_black_heart::heavy_black_heart: some string too :smiling_face:'
>>> print(set(re.findall(r':[^:]+:', x)))
{':smiling_face:', ':heavy_black_heart:'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

`print re.findall(':.*?:', x)` is doing the job.

Output:
[':heavy_black_heart:', ':heavy_black_heart:', ':smiling_face:']

But if you want to remove the duplicates:

Use:

```
res = re.findall(':.*?:', x)
dictt = {x for x in res}
print list(dictt)
```

Output:
[':heavy_black_heart:', ':smiling_face:']

Comment: `re.MULTILINE` is not doing anything with the pattern since there are no `^` and `$` to modify the behavior of. `re.match` only searches for a match at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Now, you do not have `:` in the matches.

Comment: Check now @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You do not need any capturing group, remove `(` and `)`. It will still  match `::` (not sure it is expected).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out . Capturing parentheses are removed.  No , it won't match  ::

Comment: Now, it is a duplicate of [Arun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46218974/3832970)

Comment: Use a `set` instead of `list(dict)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex:

```
:([a-z0-9:A-Z_]+):
```

Comment: When I try it, it produces ':heavy_black_heart::heavy_black_heart:'  which isn't what I want

Comment: @zwlayer It returns that match because `:` is inside the character class and `+` is a *greedy* quantifier, so all the chars defined in the character class are matched first, as many as possible occurrences, up to the last `:` that occurs after `_`, letters and digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x = 'Wish she could have told me herself. @NicoleScherzy #nicolescherzinger #OneLove #myfav #MyQueen :heavy_black_heart::heavy_black_heart: some string too :smiling_face:' 
print set(re.findall(':.*?:', x))
```

output:

```
{':heavy_black_heart:', ':smiling_face:'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a simple solution without regex. It splits around `':'` and keeps the elements with odd index:

```
>>> text = 'Wish she could have told me herself. @NicoleScherzy #nicolescherzinger #OneLove #myfav #MyQueen :heavy_black_heart::heavy_black_heart: some string too :smiling_face:'
>>> text.split(':')[1::2]
['heavy_black_heart', 'heavy_black_heart', 'smiling_face']
>>> set(text.split(':')[1::2])
set(['heavy_black_heart', 'smiling_face'])
```